# Create block matrix with secondary diagonals using Band function

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

Given matrices `m1, ... , mk` and matrices `n1, ... , nk-1`, I would like to define a block matrix
$$ m=\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}m1 & n1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & m2 & \ddots & 0 \\\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & nk-1 \\0 & \dots & 0 & mk \\\end{array}\right) $$ 
with blocks `mi` on the diagonal and blocks `nj` on the secondary diagonal. The sizes of the matrices are compatible.

I would like to define `m` as an sparse array using the Band function, but I didn't manage. Is it possible?

**Edit:** Before, I called the matrices `m[i]` and `n[j]` which was misleading, see kglr's answer

Comment: any restrictions on `Dimensions` of mi's and ni's?

Comment: @kglr actually, it would be best if the function figures out the dimensions by itself

Comment: so Dimensions of m1 and m2 are not necessarily the same (similarly for n1 and n2)?

Comment: @kglr no, they can be arbitrary

Comment: @kglr the only assumption is that they are compatible

Comment: by "compatible" you mean?

Comment: @kglr by compatible I mean that if the mi's are $k_i \times l_i$-matrices then the nj's are $k_j \times l_{j+1}$-matrices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[sA]
sA = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> #, Band[{1, 1 + Last@Dimensions[#[[1]]]}] -> #2}] &;
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
k = 4;
{rowdims, coldims} = RandomInteger[{2, 4}, {2, k}];

ClearAll[m1, m2, m3, m4, n1, n2, n3, ma, mb, mc, md, na, nb, nc];

ms = {m1, m2, m3, m4} = MapThread[Array[Function[{x, y}, Subscript[#, x, y]], #2] &, 
   {{ma, mb, mc, md}, Transpose[{rowdims, coldims}]}];

ns = {n1, n2, n3} = MapThread[Array[Function[{x, y}, Subscript[#, x, y]], #2] &, 
   {{na, nb, nc}, Transpose[{Most@rowdims, Rest@coldims}]}];

sA[ms, ns] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
sA[Map[Style[#, Blue] &, ms, {-2}], Map[Style[#, Red] &, ns, {-2}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
sa[k_Integer] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Array[m, k], 
    Band[{1, 2}] -> Array[n, k - 1]}, {k, k}];

sa[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  m(1) & n(1) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & m(2) & n(2) & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & m(3) & n(3) & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & m(4) & n(4) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m(5) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Hm, but if I replace `Array[m,k]` and `Array[n,k-1]` now by actual lists of matrices `m` and `n` and fix `k` accordingly, then the MatrixForm doesn't work anymore

Comment: I think it was my fault, I shouldn't have called the matrices `m[i]` and `n[j]` in the original post, but rather `mi` and `nj`

Comment: @BipolarMinds, please see the update.

Comment: very nice, thank you!